# Translating Stories on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cannot figure why facebook is not translating stories which action types have custom properties. For instance, I have an action type called "think_about" with a custom property called "typo". When configuring the respective story I say that I want the following text:
- "John thought Something was {typo}"

I have created the corresponding translation in Spanish. However, the translation only works if I do not send the typo when calling the opengraph api. If I send a value to the option typo, the facebook story is never translated.